# p:selectBooleanCheckbox visibility property

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am new to primefaces and JSF. I want to make selectBooleanCheckbox visible by depending on some Boolean value in my bean. But there is no visibility feature.  And if I add a panel the design changes. So do you have any suggestions?

```
  <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="idCheckbox" value="#{bean.object.value}" itemLabel="{bean.object.value.label}" styleClass="width100Percent" disabled="{bean.infomode}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add "rendered" attribute to control whether the component is displayed.

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="idCheckbox" 
                         value="#{bean.object.value}" 
                         itemLabel="#{bean.object.value.label}" 
                         styleClass="width100Percent" 
                         disabled="#{bean.infomode}"
                         rendered="#{bean.showIt}"
>
```

Comment: Like the duplicate states, No need to answer question that have perfectly matching duplicates. Better to hintbat the poster that indeed the duplicate comtains the answer